# Value not inserting into DB with select dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the value of what i get from my dropdown menu into my database. I want to insert it into info_page using cat_id of what i select from the dropdown menu code below. But for some reason the value isnt inserting. It should insert as **0 1 2 3 4** depending on how many selections i have in the dropdown but it isnt doing so. What am i doing wrong here? Below is the insert function i am using to insert cat_id's value.

```
dbConnect("INSERT INTO info_page(source, displayfrontpage, cat_id)
                    values(1,0, '".$cat[$row['pk_id']]."' )");
```

Below is how i pull my dropdown menu.

```
<select name="cat[<?=$row['pk_id']?>]">
          <?php $cat = dbConnect("SELECT * FROM category");
                if(empty($row['cat_id'])){
                ?>
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <?php
                }

          ?>


          <?php while($cat_r = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){ 

          if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_r['cat_id']){
          ?>
          <option value="<?=$cat_r[cat_id]?>" selected="selected">
                                  <?=stripslashes($cat_r[cat_name])?></option>
          <?php
          continue;
          }

          ?>
         <option value="<?=$cat_r[cat_id]?>">
              <?=stripslashes($cat_r[cat_name])?></option>
```

Comment: do you know what is the meaning of `name="cat[<?=$row['pk_id']?>]"`?

Comment: `dbConnect` is a custom function of yours, so show the code of it. Anyway, what error message does MySQL return?

Comment: I get the error `Query error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: I think its something to do with what im inserting into the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="cat[<?=$row['pk_id']?>]">
```

should be

```
<select name="cat[<?echo $row['pk_id'];?>]">
```

and so on..

Your code have many errors .use this code

```
<select name="cat[<?php echo $row['pk_id']?>]">
          <?php $cat = dbConnect("SELECT * FROM category");
                if(empty($row['cat_id'])){
                ?>
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <?php
                 while($cat_r = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){ 

          if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_r['cat_id']){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $cat_r[cat_id]?>" selected="selected">
                                  <?php echo stripslashes($cat_r['cat_name'])?></option>
          <?php
          continue;
          }

          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $cat_r['cat_id'];?>">
              <?php echo stripslashes($cat_r['cat_name']);?></option>
```

Comment: Somewhere on this line at the end `values(1,0, '".$cat[<?=$row['pk_id']?>]."' )");`

Comment: Note that `<?=` is the short tag equivalent for `<?php echo`/`<? echo`, so at least in the HTML part that should be fine in case short open tags are enabled. In the PHP part however they are totally out of place!

Comment: Yeah everything is fine it just inserts 0 not the value i want into cat_id

Comment: I think im not doing this part right `values(1,0, '".$cat[$row['pk_id']]."' )");`